# Print all times, except the ones in the DB

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, date

I need a suggestion on how to make a HTML/PHP form. I need to make a listbox with some options. At the moment I have something like these options:

```
<option value="17:00:00">17:00</option>
<option value="18:00:00">18:00</option>
<option value="19:00:00">19:00</option>
```

In my db, I have two columns: ID and time.

Let's suppose I have a row with ID: 1 and time: 18:00:00.

How can I make it so it doesn't appear in my listbox? Of course I already opened the connection to the DB.

Thanks for any suggestions!

EDIT: why downvotes? What's wrong in my question? I don't really understand this community sometimes.

Comment: Have a table of all times and IDs and grab from there IDs not in the other table. Have an array, grab from the table, if in array, delete it.

Comment: By just opening connection you won't get the data from db. You have to fire a query on it.

Comment: I know this Rikesh, I wrote it just to make you know I'm only trying to find a logic for the query to use, I don't want the whole code including the DB connection opening.

Comment: [What, exactly, have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. with DB query fetch the values so that you get something like `$blacklist = array('18:00','19:00')`
2. check for time being black-listed with `if(!in_array('18:00', $blacklist)){...}`

if you have white-listed values as array, and you don't want to check in viewing part, then its better to use array_diff as @YaK answered

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$all_times = array('17:00:00', '18:00:00' ...) ;
$times_in_db = fetchTimes($your_db); // expected to return an array of all 'times' in your DB
$diff = array_diff($all_times, $times_in_db);

foreach ($diff as $time) {
    echo "<option value=\"$time\">$time</option>";
}
```